# How can I increase a USB printer driver timeout value in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, printing

I have a specialized printer that requires a warm-up of about a minute or so. When I spool the print job, the printer starts to warm up but this soon causes the print driver to pop the "Error Printing" error. Eventually, the printer will warm up and proceed to print. And wast majority of time, the driver will resume spooling with no issues. However, besides the annoyance of errors, occasionally the printer will stop the job in the middle and restart again, presumably from the driver only sending partial data and then restarting once the error clears.

Is there a way to increase the timeout value for a specific (USP port) printer? If not is there a way to stop it from creating the error condition? Thanks.

Comment: My printer can also take a long time to become available, but I never had a timeout. It's possible that this is a problem with the driver. Which printer is it and have you installed any driver?